# VSTO merged cells

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, oledb

Is there any way in VSTO (/JET OLEDB or other methods of reading excel files) to tell if the data comes from a single cell or merged range of cells and get this range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest route here is to make use of the Boolean `Range.MergeCells` property.

Assuming that your cell reference were named `myCell`, you could use something like:

```
if (myCell.MergeCells)
{
    // The 'myCell' is part of a merged cell area.
}
Else
{
   // The 'myCell' is not part of any merged cell area.
}
```

You could also check the `Cells.Count` on the Range returned by the `Range.MergeArea` property:

```
if (myCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1) {...}
```

or:

```
if (myCell.MergeArea.Count > 1) {...}
```

The last example works because the Range.Count property always returns the same value as does the Range.Cells.Count, by design.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the you use a method that can invoke & use the Excel object model, you check the MergeArea property of a cell to see if it contains anything other than that cell.  If it does, then that cell is part of a MergeArea.  Here's how I've done it in VBA:

```
IF CurrCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count > 1 Or CurrCell.MergeArea.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    'CurrCell is part of a MergeArea... '
```

The equivalent C# VSTO code should be fairly similar.

Comment: this is very interesting, I will check that solution and mark as answered if it does the job.